# Session variables fail to work when executing function using cron's "GET" command

Tags: php, cron, session-variables, openshift

I am trying to access session variables of a function setup using a cron job on openshift in PHP. I have setup the cron using GET command of PHP and it hits the url every minute. However I am unable to access session variables declared in the function and the script fails everytime. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you write that you "setup the cron using GET command of PHP"?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I have written the cron something like this: GET http://myurl.com/myfunction

Comment: If that does anything, then it's not the cron that is commonly known, as that only executes programs. See also the description of the according tag.